# Update column value with sum of a column from records of a different table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

I have two tables payroll_est_act, actual_payroll_history

```
payroll_est_act

id| location_id     | type          | amt
-------------------------------------------
1 | 1               |  Actual       | 36000  
2 | 1               |  Estimated    | 20000   
3 | 2               |  Actual       | 50000  
4 | 2               |  Estimated    | 50000 
5 | 3               |  Actual       | 24000  
6 | 3               |  Estimated    | 18000 


actual_payroll_history

id  |  payroll_est_act_id   | amt       | date
-----------------------------------------------------
1   |   1                   |   4000    |   1 June 20
2   |   1                   |   4000    |   1 July 20
3   |   1                   |   4000    |   1 Aug 20
4   |   1                   |   4000    |   1 Sep 20
5   |   2                   |   12500   |   1 June 20
6   |   2                   |   12500   |   1 July 20
7   |   2                   |   12500   |   1 Aug 20
8   |   2                   |   12500   |   1 Sep 20
9   |   3                   |   4000    |   1 June 20
```

I want to write an update statement to update the amount in payroll_est_act for 'actual' type with the sum of amounts for the corresponding payroll_est_act_id from actual_payroll_history if the value of amt from payroll_est_act does not match with the sum of amt from actual_payroll_history.

Please help.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use an updatable CTE here:

```sql
WITH cte1 AS (
    SELECT payroll_est_act_id, SUM(amt) AS amt_actual
    FROM actual_payroll_history
    GROUP BY payroll_est_act_id
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT p.amt, t.amt_actual
    FROM payroll_est_act p
    INNER JOIN cte1 t
        ON t.payroll_est_act_id = p.location_id
    WHERE p.type = 'Actual'
)

UPDATE cte2
SET amt = amt_actual
WHERE amt <> amt_acutal;
```

Comment: This works, but if I select from cte2 just to check the records, I received an error - "Cannot convert a char value to money. The char value has incorrect syntax."  on SELECT payroll_est_act_id, SUM(amt) AS amt_actual, how do I avoid this?

Comment: Without knowing your exact data and table definitions, I can only speculate.  It sounds like the `SUM()` is causing the issue, possibly because you're trying to sum character data.

Comment: my bad, i used some different column for p.type = 'actual', Thanks